# I2C slave device model for testing?

Tags: i2c

Has anyone come across a real manufacturer-supplied device model that I can use for testing an I2C master, in VHDL or Verilog?

I've had a look through the Opencores slave models, and the testbenches for masters, but there's nothing obvious - too many reported bugs, too little functionality, not documented, and so on.

**EDIT**

To clarify, what I'm looking for is a device model for a slave, which conforms to the I2C specification, ie. NXP UM10204. It would be nice if it contained R/W registers, as this will simplify testing. It would be nice if it could stretch the clock.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? I2C is simple enough that physical-layer correctness (protocol and timing) can be verified by inspecting the waveforms. Higher-level functionality tends to be very device-specific. For example, I have had to write I2C slave models that had just enough functionality to allow an FPGA to complete its system initialization, but it was by no means a complete simulation of the device in question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Everything specifically I2C-related, at a digital level - timing, protocol, S, P, Sr, slave addressing, slave ACK, slave NACK on bad address, writing data to slave, reading data back from slave, multiple slaves, bus turnaround, clock stretch, yada yada, self-checking, no eyeballing/waveforms. Yes, higher-level protocol - number of registers, width, whether they're R/W, and so on - varies, but this is easy to adapt to and any model is better than none.

Comment: please edit your question to include the information in the comment .... then delete the comment

Comment: @jsotola: The comment is simply background information on what I'd like to test in my master, as requested, and would unnecessarily complicate the question. My requirements don't impact on the model itself. A slave model will simply respond to I2C requests.

Comment: @EML The background information is critical to your question. There are many slaves on the market that don't do clock stretching, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I2C specifications define certain timing ranges for every signal edge. If you are serious about verification of your master, you need a model that does include both timing boundaries, worst cases, not just the "golden" middle.

Quality of the model would eventually determine the quality of product and thus its acceptance in marketplace, so this is business, and no-one would share with you tools that give a product some business advantage. So you would need either to write your own good model, or pay big bucks for a full IP package from someone like Synopsis.

Having a good model is a serious job, and it doesn't come cheap.

Comment: The board this goes on uses 5 different SPI slave devices, which I pay for. I think it's reasonable that if you manufacture and sell an I2C device then you should supply a model for it, so that the purchaser can confirm that they can drive it. The manufacturers, in this case, disagree. So, I'm asking here in case anyone knows of a manufacturer who does happen to provide a model, which would be better than nothing.

Comment: Why should a manufacturer provide a VHDL or Verilog model of their IC? Are you not validating that it works correctly in circuit?

Comment: I'd like to delete this question, but I can't, because you've provided an answer. I don't wish to be rude, but your "answer" does not address the question, is obvious, and is of no value to the community. I have spent over 25 years designing *and* verifying ASICs and FPGAs, I know all about timing (and there is no "golden middle"), I know exactly what a good model is, I know how to spell Synopsys, and I also know that nobody is going to pay "big bucks for a full IP package" to verify I2C. So, please delete your answer, and I'll delete the question.

Comment: @EML, since you know this all about everything and even know how to spell, I found your question very illuminating. If you don't know what the "shmoo" is and don't include edge jitter into your device models, then I am sorry about your products and overall experience. If you didn't get it, people who design devices don't have "device models", they have good "master model". Their "device model" is their RTL, which they won't share with you. No one will spend a man-year to include variable timing for free, as you requested in comments.

Comment: @EML For these reasons I believe my answer has certain value to community, and I refuse your offer.